# Eclipse export JAR and maintain directories

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar

I have a resource folder where I keep images for my project.

So my structure ends up being

```
Project
  -src
  -bin
  -res
```

Res is the folder that contains my images, and in my code, images are referenced like so.

```
"res/image.jpg"
```

That works fine when I run my project from within Eclipse, however if I wish to export it to a runnable JAR file, it puts all of the images into the root folder within the JAR. Is there any way to make it put the images in a res folder within the JAR?

Comment: You shoud use Maven build tool, in `pom.xml` file, you will define resource directory relative path. You will catch what you want.

Comment: Check "Add directory entries" in the export options for the Jar.

Comment: Edit:, nevermind thank you, add directory entries worked, I didn't notice I still had the res folder added as a source from when I was messing around with it before. Thank you.